# Type 'echo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list

Tags: command-line, server, 16.04, software-installation, mongodb

I am trying to install [mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) on the ubuntu server 16.04 LTS.

for that I have created file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list` and added a line as per the doc.

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
```

Now when I try to download the package list using `sudo apt-get update` it is giving me below error.

```
nodev@ubuntu:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get update
E: Type 'echo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: You're nearly there. You should have executed the line starting with "echo" as a command - it would have added the correct text to the .list file. Instead, you added the whole command. Either delete that line and execute the statement, or modify the line to keep only `deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse`.

Comment: @Jos you may as well post that as an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are nearly there.

In order to install MongoDB and keep up with updates, you need to create a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` (you did that) and add a single line to it. To make adding that line easier for you, the authors of the installation instructions provided a one-line command that would do that. You should have copied that command and executed it in a terminal. What you did instead was editing the file and pasting the whole command in it. The `apt` command will obviously not accept that. What you need to do is either:

1. delete the file, recreate the empty file, and execute the command (with `sudo` in front of it, I should mention); or
2. edit the file, strip away everything around `deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse`, and save the file.

Comment: Oof, I interpreted the mongo instructions the exact same way as OP did.